# Printing text in color

Tags: python, colors, termcolor

I am trying to print a text in a different color. I have already installed [termcolor](https://pypi.org/project/termcolor/), but when type:

```
from termcolor import colored
print(colored("hello","blue"))
```

it appears

```
[34mhello[0m .
```

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your problem. Could you provide more details about your environment: OS, where you are running this code, and python version?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50447424/7758804) is specific to `termcolor`

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3332860/7758804) may be a better option for windows.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: `pip install colorama`

And seconds:

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
print(Fore.GREEN + Back.RED + Style.DIM + "hello world")
```

(This is an example, whole pip package usage * description [click here](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/))

For some unknown reason for me when I open CMD & try it doesn't work BUT when I code in VSCode & run from there with terminal window as CMD it works fine.